# How to enable imagecreatefromgif/imagecreatefromjpeg/imagecreatefrompng in PHP?

Tags: php

It now gives:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()
```

But the gd library is enabled.

Comment: Does phpinfo() agree that gd is enabled?

Comment: Yes,I can call imagepng with no problem.

Answer (score 7):

Install php5-gd:

on deb-based system:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

If you are using php-fpm then restart it:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

Found this [solution here](https://druss.co/2015/01/fix-call-to-undefined-function-imagecreatefromgif/)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.x-gd` with 'x' as the current version of PHP for the last ones.

Comment: On current Debian stretch, after installing `php-gd` I had to enable the `php7.3` module, as this didn't pull `php7.0-gd`

Answer (score 3):

Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#70832

It might be that your JPEG library is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

if using ubuntu, just install the with the command
$ `sudo apt install php-gd`